# Do orders get printed after sale is closed via POS API

Tags: square-connect

I am currently building an integration with the Square POS API. I understand my app would redirect the user to the Square POS to close the transaction. I know you can play around with the information transferred to the Square app, like payment option, or payment amount, as well as notes. Would those notes be printed with the receipt?

We are doing an app similar to the coffee example and after an order is paid, we'd like to use our user's already set up printer and Square integration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have your Square POS setup to print, things will get printed regardless if they care created from a custom app or in Square Point of Sale.

Your notes will not be printed on the receipt.

Comment: How would the kitchen know what to make? Let's say you choose a mocha that costs $4.99. It would make no sense to print just $4.99. The reason why I was wondering about the notes is that of the kitchen. How can they know what needs to be made?

Thanks for your help!